# How to register HasEventHandlers to a self created GWT-Widget?

Tags: java, gwt, mgwt

Iam creating a own Button Widget and want to register the HasClickHandlers and HasMouseoverHandlers on this Widget.
The problem is when iam using this Widget and add a ClickHandler, there is no reaction.

```
MyButton extends Widget implements HasClickHandlers, HasMouseOverHandlers{

    Element elem;
    Element child1;
    Element child2;

    public MyButton(String txt1, String txt2){

          elem = Document.get().createDivElement();
          child1 = Document.get().createDivElement();
          child2 = Document.get().createDivElement();

          child1.setInnerText(txt1);
          child2.setInnerText(txt2);


         elem.appendChild(child1);
         elem.appendChild(child2);

         setStyleName(elem, "elem");
         setStyleName(child1, "child1");
         setStyleName(child1, "child2");

         setElement(elem);
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
         return this.addHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseOverHandler(MouseOverHandler handler) {
            return this.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOverEvent.getType());
    }



}
```

Now iam using this widget, what should be a button.

```
MyButton b1 = new MyButton("Hello", "People");
b1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("Hi");
        }
    });
```

There is no reaction on this click.

```
b1.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {

            anotherWidget.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("yellow");
        }
    });
```

The mouseOverHandler works but not the clickHandler.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `addClickHandler` function like this.

```
 public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
         return this.addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
```

When you simply add your handler it will not synchronized with DOM events, or to use `addHandler` you need to specify the synchronization explicitly   like,

```
int typeInt = Event.getTypeInt(ClickEvent.getType().getName());       
sinkEvents(typeInt);
```